# MSI SuperCharger on ubuntu

Tags: usb, hardware, msi

Is there a way to get MSI super charger working on Ubuntu.  My motherboard is MSI Z97 Gaming 7.

Comment: Any control in bios ?

Comment: Not anything obvious

Answer (score 2):

There are a few programs from different mainboard manufacturers with functionality to increase power output on USB ports, but I wasn't able to find an equivalent for Linux. The closest I could find was some program to charge iPads with no clear reference what it really does. I assume that this functionality is not currently implemented in the Linux kernel or nobody tried solving this problem before, coming up with a popular solution. Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think the windows app swaps the usb port from data to charger using one dedicated port.That port automatically turns to charge when windows sleeps. I wonder what it does if using MSI linux based winki 3